# Calculation in HAVING clause

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with the following SQL query (MySQL):

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(SUBSTR(STORE.VALUE, LOCATE('timestamp":', STORE.VALUE)+11),13) AS UNSIGNED) as starttime
FROM STORE
HAVING starttime <= MIN(starttime)+600000;
```

This query returns 1 value: `1344543364317` this is the minimum value of the column starttime.

The following query where the calculation is done manually returns more values.

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(SUBSTR(STORE.VALUE, LOCATE('timestamp":', STORE.VALUE)+11),13) AS UNSIGNED) as starttime
FROM STORE
HAVING starttime <= 1344543964317;
```

Why does this query return more values?

**Edit**

Some more explanation about the data:
Unfortunately most of the data is pretty useless. Basically the table only contains two columns: Key, Value. Key is not important here. The Value contains stuff like this: `{"changeset":"Z:1>6b|5+6b$Welcome to Etherpad Lite!\n\nThis pad text is synchronized as you type, so that everyone viewing this page sees the same text. This allows you to collaborate seamlessly on documents!\n\nEtherpad Lite on Github: http://j.mp/ep-lite\n","meta":{"author":"","timestamp":1344543364317,"atext":{"text":"Welcome to Etherpad Lite!\n\nThis pad text is synchronized as you type, so that everyone viewing this page sees the same text. This allows you to collaborate seamlessly on documents!\n\nEtherpad Lite on Github: http://j.mp/ep-lite\n\n","attribs":"|6+6c"}}}`

So I'm basically just extracting the timestamp value and displaying it as a virtual column called starttime. The first 10 values of the starttime column are

```
1344543364317
1344543365939
1344543366439
1344543366454
1344543368794
1344553433259
1344553434054
1344553499779
1344553500871
1344553502104
```

Comment: Give some sample data. So that we can find the solution.

Comment: I tried giving some data, see edit of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your value, 1344543964317, is way bigger than 4294967295, which is the biggest possible value for a `UNSIGNED` integer. Use `BIGINT` instead.

Comment: Okay, I expected something like, but read somewhere that a unsigned int are interpreted as BIGINT. How do I convert this to a BIGINT? MySQL seems not to support that out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant, but I have a solution. It seems you can't use `startttime` on the right side of the equation, so you need to redo the original calculation.

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(SUBSTR(VALUE, LOCATE('timestamp":', VALUE)+11),13) AS UNSIGNED) AS starttime
FROM STORE
HAVING starttime <= 
    (SELECT MIN(CAST(LEFT(SUBSTR(STORE.VALUE, LOCATE('timestamp":', STORE.VALUE)+11),13) AS UNSIGNED)) FROM STORE) + 60000
```